# How can I programmatically determine the capabilities of an optical drive in Win32

Tags: winapi, dvd, optical-drive

I'm trying to create a deployment tool that will install software based on the hardware found on a system. I'd like the tool to be able to determine if the optical drive is a writer (to determine if burning software sould be installed) or can read DVDs (to determine if a player should be installed). I tried uing the following code

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_CDROMDrive")
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "MediaType: " & objItem.MediaType
Next
```

but it always respons with CD-ROM

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI to enumerate what Windows knows about a drive; get the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx) instance from which you should be able to grab the the [`Win32_PhysicalMedia`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346(VS.85).aspx) information for the physical media the drive uses; the [MediaType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346(VS.85).aspx) property to get what media it uses (CD, CDRW, DVD, DVDRW, etc, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Platform SDK - IDiscMaster::EnumDiscRecorders (XP / 2003)

DirectX and DirectShow has extensive interfaces to work with DVD

Else enumerate disk drives and try firing a DeviceIonControlCode that supports extarcting the type info.

Good luck